# Trying to create a copy-constructor, how can i fix this problem?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I have made a copy constructor and I am trying to initialize a buffer of the same size of rhs but i am getting an error. I am expecting a container being created with the same size of the rhs with the help of the size() function in the class.

```
int_buffer::int_buffer(const int_buffer& rhs): ptr_begin(new int[rhs.size()]){
    std::cout << "Copy Constructor running..." << '\n';
    std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
}
```

size

```
size_t int_buffer::size(){
    return ptr_end - ptr_begin;
}
```

The error i am receiving is:
The object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "int_buffer::size" object type is: const int_buffer.

**SOLUTION**

```
size_t int_buffer::size() const{
    return ptr_end - ptr_begin;
}
```

The solution to my problem was that my size function was not a const.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]. From error message though it seems that `size()` is not a const method.

Comment: THank you, i will try to edit my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `int_buffer::size` method is not const. It should have a signature like

```
std::size_t int_buffer::size() const;
```

The reason is because you are passing `const int_buffer& rhs` so you cannot call any non-const methods off of that object.

Comment: Even when correct, answering a low-quality question only encourages more low-quality questions.

Comment: Why is this a low quality question? They have a small snippet of code and enough of the compilation error to identify the issue. There's definitely some improvements the OP could make, but seems like a fine question to me, which is why I answered it.

Comment: Yeah why not downvote my question so i get banned, not even argumenting why it is a low-quality question. Like i said before i am gonna edit, not done yet! That is a big reason why people get banned and can never come back from it.

Comment: To be fair, you could have Googled that error message and got your solution really quickly; your question shows no research effort. I haven't downvoted it but let's not go overboard defending this question.

Comment: @CoryKramer it lacked MCVE when I posted my comment. Now, when MCVE is there, it is OK